# RLINK32: Error opening file "...\Data.DFM". Occurs the first time I build a project after opening Delphi

Tags: delphi

I get this error the first time I build/compile a particular project after opening Delphi (D6 Pro). Subsequent builds do not give the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error can be caused by an exception being raised in a design component on the form. If the component is running some initialisation code which raises an exception this error will be produced. This can be shown by adding

```
raise Exception.CreateFmt('Test', []);
```

into the code of the component. Note that in D6 Pro this does not produce 'Test' in the error message. The underlying exception message is not displayed.

Comment: I don't think so: Simply building/compiling an project doesn't Create the components on the forms. Opening up the forms causes the creation of the components, but the OP is complaining about the first build, not the first time the form is opened.

Comment: Hi Cosmin, Maybe 'initialisation' is the wrong word. The component that caused the RLINK32 was TffServerEngine which I was testing with some new exception messages. I wanted it to generate one of these so I could see the new message had compiled properly and I hard-coded it to always produce an exception in one of the file handling routines. If you have the NoAutoSaveCfg property False it writes to some tables such as FFSINFO.FF2 during the first build/compile, at least when I do it in the IDE anyway, I did not test the command line. I got the RLINK32 error on first build/compile in the IDE.

Comment: This is what I understand: You wrote an "IDE Expert" that plugs into the IDE and raises an exception when the IDE first tries to save a file? Well then, your IDE is behaving correctly! What did you expect it to do? Also your answer to your own question is ambiguous, please define "some initialisation code" (for most of that's the components constructor), and please define "code of the component" - what's that?

Comment: I can find no reference to "IDE Expert" in D6 Pro. I guess this feature was introduced in D7. No, I have not written an IDE Expert.

I am debugging a database called FlashFiler:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpflashfiler/

It contains a 'Component' called TffServerEngine. See p.407 of the FlashFiler pdf documentation for details.

The function I am editing is in fffile.inc which contains the low level file access routines. The function is FFPositionFilePrim32 which seeks to a position in a file.

When I forced an exception in this function I got the RLINK32 error when building my project.

Comment: The D6 Pro help page for the RLINK32 error suggests these possibilities: Dupicate resource name. Corrupted resource file. Unsupported resource type such as 16-bit. Problems upgrading a resource from 16 to 32 bit.  
  
None of these are correct for my exception. The RLINK32 error message gives no idea of the true origin of the problem. Ideally it should provide the text of the exception that was raised in the TffServerEngine Component.

Answer (score 8):

I have the same issue, it was fixed by replacing **{$R *.dfm}** directive in the problem unit (which was not found by Delphi during first compilation) by more specific clause **{$R fMain.dfm}**.

Comment: could you explain step by step how to do this?

Comment: Encountered this behaviour for the first time in 15 years, and this solved it. Interestingly enough my filenames are also exactly `fMain`.

Comment: While that rename did help me here (thanks!), I just found I had to _build_ my project (instead of _compiling_). Crux was I modified and recompiled the source of an already installed component. Quite misleading error message.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably caused by a control that raises an exception during its creation (when the form is loaded).

---

How I solved this (this case was specific for me, but a very similar solution may apply to you):

First I loaded the 'broken' unit into the IDE. It didn't caused an error until I pressed F12 to see the form. The error message raised by the IDE was not very helpful, but after changing the {$R *.dfm} to {$R MainForm.dfm}, the error message changed to something more specific. More exactly, in the error report, one line was of special interest:

```
{MyControls_XE.bpl} StrGrdBase.TBaseStrGrid.FixCursor (Line 569, "StrGrdBase.pas" + 9) + $8
```

I navigated to that line and I have seen that in some conditions I was trying to set focus on the second row, while the grid had only one row.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error on Deplhi 2010, the problem was there was a component which has not been installed in IDE, when I changed the component to the one that exists it is worked as a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an additional reason for this behaviour: DFM files are rejected if a property is placed below any child objects owned by the main object. In other words, a TButton object should be defined below the last property of the TPanel object that the button is placed on. Tested with D2010, compiling with bcc32